# Vue 2 - Importing google font does not work on build

Tags: html, css, vue.js, google-font-api, google-fonts

In a project I'm trying to import the font 'Encode Sans', this seems to work on localhost, but when build, font is not working.

I have a global stylesheet with the following:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Encode+Sans:wght@400;600;700;800&display=swap');


body {
  font-family: 'Encode Sans', sans-serif;
  background: $backgroundColor;
}
```

I've tried to import throught creating a `public/index.html` file with `<link>`, but that did not solve it either and I would prefer to not have to font locally.

To make my question more clear, this is the result:

- Build:
  [image: Build font]
- Localhost:
  [image: Localhost font]

Comment: What does your built CSS look like?

Comment: Define "font is not working". Also, why don't you want it locally? It's better in pretty much every aspect.

Comment: Can you replicate your development env in code sandbox or any other online platform to better understand what's causing the issue?

Comment: Or feel free to share a public Github repo.

Comment: I define font not working as in; it falls back to the `sans-serif` font and does not use the `Encode Sans`.

The css build shows this: 
`@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Encode+Sans:wght@400;600;700;800&display=swap);
body{font-family:"Encode Sans",sans-serif;background:#f2f2f2}`

Comment: Ill update the original question with pictures

Comment: The font is not loading in the network tab?

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I went with downloading the font and adding it to the project, replacing the `@import` with `@font-face` for desired changes. This solved my issues

Comment: It's better that way anyway!